# Is there a json validation framework in play based on a specified grammar

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

An automated system is going to feed the application[Play with Scala] with JSON's and the contract of the integration is that there would be no validation required on JSON's since it will be always deemed right. But for testing purposes when we seed the data more often than not we are not able to send the correct JSONs. We would like to validate the JSON's we receive based on a set of grammars. Is there a library that already does this. Or is there a better way to do this?

Example: Grammar for valid Json :

```
"header"->[String, mandatory], 
"footer"->[String], 
"someArray"->Array[String, mandatory], 
"someArrayObject"->Array[
                         {
                          {"key1"->Int, mandatory},
                          {"key2"->String}
                         }, 
                         mandatory
                        ]
```

and passing,

```
{  
   "header":"headerContent", 
   "footer":"footerContent", 
   "someArray":["str1", "str2"], 
   "someArrayObject"->[
                       {"key1":4, "key2":"someStringValue"},
                       {"key1":5, "key2":"someOtherStringValue"}
                      ]
} // would pass

{  
   "header":"headerContent", 
   "footer":"footerContent",
   "someArray":["str1", "str2"]
} // would notpass since someArrayObject though declared mandatory is not provided in the sample json
```

Answer (score 3):

I think play-json will satisfy you [play-json](https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-alone)

In play-json you don't create a validator as it is, but a json transformer which is a validator in itself. The author of the framework wrote a series of blog-posts to show how to work with it: [json-transformers](http://mandubian.com/2012/10/29/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part3-json-transformers/)

* Haven't noticed you use play) Play has play-json included by default.

Comment: json-transformers does not satisfy our requirements. We are using [Embedded document pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EmbeddedDocument.html) which do not have proper models and play-json validators does not work with it.

Comment: how you would validate something which doesn't define proper models? Sounds like a zen koan to me. If I understand "Embedded document pattern" correctly, than one way to realize it would be to deserialize json into case classes, at which play-json is good at. Anyway json-transformers are very general mechanism with which you can do basically anything with json, so if transformers (or Reads/Writes) cannot handle your use case, maybe the use case is wrong?

Comment: Ok we will explore json-transformers further and get back to you. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to roll out your own DSLs. This is why we have schemas. Just like using XML schemas to validate your XML docs, you can define a JSON schema to validate your JSON objects. I had a similar requirement when building a RESTful web service using Play. I solved it by using the [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) library.

I have used the JSON Schema draft v3.  The library supports draft v3 and draft v4. You can validate your schemas against possible JSON inputs using a web application that uses the same library. The web app is hosted [here](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/).

Also there are pretty nice examples that use the draft v4. You can check them out from [here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/examples).

In Play 2, I have composed an action that takes the schema resource file name as input. This keeps away a lot of JSON validation code from the controller action itself.

```
@JsonValidate("user-register.json")
public static Result create() {
    ...
}
```

This way, all JSON Validation code stays in one place. Pretty neat :)